# AWS API keeps rejecting my request based on failing authenticity

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to make use of the Amazon API to retrieve product information for an app I am developing.  I signed up with Amazon and created an access ID and a secret key.  I found this site on the web which I am using to create my Signature

> https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#js

I am making use of the JavaScript implementation I found on that site.  This implementation takes in 2 parameters, a message string and a secret key.  This is the message string I am sending in:

> http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Large&SearchIndex=All&IdType=UPC&ItemId=5000159459228&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIHI7RHJARE24DVBA&Timestamp=2018-08-11T13:02:01Z

As the second parameter, I am sending in my Amazon secret Key.  When the function returns the signiture, I cut it and pasted it into the string I am sending to Amazon.  This is what the resulting string looks like:

> http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Large&SearchIndex=All&IdType=UPC&ItemId=5000159459228&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIHI7RHJARE24DVBA&Timestamp=2018-08-11T13:02:01Z&Signature=52c173bdaa24c9847cc2ee2af7e4282c0bcd2a0246f2c4c8a5611b52fe5ce011

The message I get back from Amazon is this

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

I can only assume that Amazon is generating a signature that differs from the one I am sending.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is your signature hex-encoded?  Docs specify base64.

Comment: Pls Ignore the v4 links I have given in my deleted answer. As @Michael mentioned its V2. BTW see if you can use this https://webservices.amazon.com/scratchpad/index.html to compare your generated signurates against what the scratch pad generates.

Comment: in order to use the scratch pad, I have to sign up as an affiliate and it asks me for my web site url or mobile app.  I have neither as this is a work in progress.